# How to use CachedNetworkImage with different Cache Managers?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-image, image-caching

Im caching images in my Flutter App which im fetching from my Firebase Storage. I use the cached_network_image package and the flutter_cache_manager for the caching part.

Some images I just want to cache for a few days, others for a very long time or when the user deletes them. Is there a way to do that with this package? I know I could create different custom cache manager and set different stale periods. Would that be the way I should go for? Or should I use the the package only for the short time caching and another method for the long term storing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Set the duration according to your needs.

```
final CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager(
    Config(
        'the_key',
        stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 3),//secs, mins...
    ),
);
```

If it's something that rarely changes you can even increase the number of days.
I strongly recommend setting a key so maintenance is easier whenever you need to do it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**